# Two iPhone Dev Licenses on one Mac?

Tags: iphone

I have an odd situation.  I have a macbook that I use for work and I am an approved iPhone developer, etc.  I would like to build iPhone apps to put out under my name (they should be kept and tracked separately from the work license I have, since that really belongs to the organization and not me), but I don't want to buy another mac.  Can I create another admin user account on my Macbook that would be used with another (personal) developer certificate, or can there only be one dev license per machine?

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same exact situation.  You can use the same Mac and the same account on that machine.

Just follow the same steps as before when you setup the Developer Certificate for your company.  Essentially, your Keychain will contain multiple certificates that you can use to sign your applications.

What certificate you use is chosen on an application by application basis through XCode.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the quick response (I've been trying to get Apple to answer for a week now)!

Comment: You can have as many dev or distribution licenses on the same mac as you want. I have quite a few certificates installed on my mac.